# checking if an object is an Exception class

Tags: python

I've got some code which does:

```
try:
    result = func()
except StandardError as e:
    result = e
```

How can I check whether `result` contains an Exception?

<del>Using `isinstance(result, Exception)` doesn't work as exceptions are a class, not an instance, e.g. `type(ValueError)` gives `<type 'type'>`.</del>

--- Edit ---

Well that was stupid; while the above code was a correct distillation of how I was using `func()`, what my test `func()` was doing was `return ValueError`, not `raise ValueError`. With the former returning the class and the latter returning an instance. So the problem wasn't as described.

Comment: um... have you actually tried `isinstance(result, Exception)`? works for me since `e` is an __instance__ of `StandardError` not the class `StandardError` itself.

Comment: Why does your code do that?

Comment: In your code, `e` will be an instance of `StandardError` if your exception handler ran... I'm not sure what your last paragraph is supposed to mean...

Comment: This seems like an XY problem to me: perhaps you can step back and tell us what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd be curious to understand what you're trying to achieve by first storing one of two unrelated things in the same variable, to only later have difficulty figuring out which of the two things is stored there.

Comment: I recommend designing your code to be simpler, and thus avoiding this question altogether: set `result=None` and use a different name, eg `err = e` for the error.  Then you can easily know if you have an error or a result: if `err is None` then no error and result is good otherwise you have an error.

Comment: For those curious as to why this was even desired, it's part of something kind of like `concurrent.futures`, i.e. functions get run asynchronously and their return/exception values handled somewhere else. I take the point about storing the return value and exceptions in the same place though.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Though I am convinced that this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that requires rethinking the logic of your design, here is an answer to your immediate question: `isinstance` works fine:

```
>>> try:
...     int('a')
... except ValueError as e:
...     result = e
...
>>> type(result)
<class 'ValueError'>
>>> isinstance(result, Exception)
True
```

Your problem is that you were testing `ValueError` (the class), not `e` (an instance of a `ValueError`). Perhaps the following example with a `bool` (which subclasses an `int`) will make this clearer:

```
>>> isinstance(bool, int)
False
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone googling the subject and refusing to think they have run into XY problem:

You can access the type of any exception by instancing it and checking its type.
Normally we use "str" and such to refer to a class, but to access the class for an exception we will have to instance it:

```py
>>> type(ZeroDivisionError())
>>> <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>
```