# How do I detect in python if the type of return value if it is an Error

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a function which either returns a dataframe or an Exception.

```
def func():
   try:
       # try creating a dataframe df
       return df
   except BaseException as error:
       return error

def func2():
   return_value = func()
   if return_value is an exception:
      # do this
   else:
      # do that
```

Another function calls it and I want to know if the return object is a dataframe or an exception.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: just use a try: except: there as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170269/checking-if-an-object-is-an-exception-class

Comment: I answered it because I knew, but the SO post by @Guy has all the info you need

Comment: Don't return exceptions! Exceptions should use the exception mechanism. Returning them is missing the point.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica is absolutely correct.  `func` shouldn't be catching the exception.  If `func2` is interested in handling the exception, then it should be the one catching it.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the context of what you want to accomplish, you can use `isinstance(return_value, Exception)`. It should do what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you take an approach like this:

```
def func():
    try:
       # try creating a dataframe df
        return True, df
    except BaseException as error:
        return False, error

def func2():
    success, return_value = func()
    if not success:
        # do this
    else:
        # do that
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help. Return df or None and easy to check the return value.

```py
from contextlib import suppress

def func():
    with suppress(BaseException):
        # try creating a dataframe df
        return df

def func2():
    retval = func() # None or df
```